# Testcafe custom reporter doesn't return from this.formatError

Tags: automation, automated-tests, report, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm trying to implement a custom reporter for testcafe. If there is an error in testcase and this.formatError is called, it is not returning from this.formatError. Just hangs there indefinitely, I need to manually ctrl-c to stop the testcafe process. But if I remove this.formatError and try again it is working. What could be the reason?

Below is the code for reportTestDone()

```
    reportTestDone (name, testRunInfo, meta) {

        const errors      = testRunInfo.errs;
        const warnings    = testRunInfo.warnings;
        const hasErrors   = !!errors.length;
        const hasWarnings = !!warnings.length;
        const result      = hasErrors ? this.chalk.red('failed') 
            : this.chalk.green('passed');

        const title = `${result} ${name} @ ${meta.page}`;

        this.write(title)
            .newline();

        if (hasErrors) {
            this.write('Errors:')
                .newline();

            errors.forEach((error, idx) => {
                this.setIndent(4)
                    .write(this.formatError(error, `${idx + 1} `)) //<-- this line is the problem
                    .write(error.errMsg)
                    .newline();
            });
            this.setIndent(0);
        }

        if (hasWarnings) {
            this.newline()
                .write('Warnings:');

            warnings.forEach(warning => {
                this.newline()
                    .write(warning);
            });
        }
        this.setIndent(0);
     }
```

Comment: Ok, looks createErrorDecorator() was the problem. while generating the reporter it created code for createErrorDecorator() also. After removing this code, its working.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your findings. I recommend that you post them as an answer.